# Why can't I pipe a file to "tar" from "curl" with a Docker image for Debian?

Tags: docker

Why is the following failing on a Docker image for Debian Jessie?

```
# curl --silent --show-error --location https://download.owncloud.org/community/owncloud-8.0.3.tar.bz2 | tar xjv
tar (grandchild): bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (grandchild): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child died with signal 13
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
curl: (23) Failed writing body (4096 != 16384)
```

I can't run that inside Dockerfile *RUN* statements, or in an interactive bash shell for the image "php:5.6-fpm" (based off "debian:jessie").

I can, however, run it on lots of other Debian and Ubuntu systems.

Is this a problem with Docker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message seems pretty clear:

```
tar (grandchild): bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
```

`bzip2` isn't present in the `debian:jessie` instance, so if you want to use bzip2 compression, you have to install bzip2 first with `apt-get install bzip2`.